# setAlarmClock() is not exact and system adjusts the time for it

Tags: android, kotlin, alarm, android-alarms

Android documentation for `setAlarmClock`:

> Invoke an alarm at a precise time in the future. Because these alarms are highly visible to users, **the system never adjusts their delivery time**. The system identifies these alarms as the most critical ones and leaves low-power modes if necessary to deliver the alarms.

But it looks like system does adjust delivery time of alarm.

Code(Kotlin):

```
val intent = Intent(context, AlarmService::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0)
val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

alarmService.setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(epochMillis, null), intent)
```

The alarm was set for a minute, but system adjusted it.
It must be invoked in `20:34:26`, but actually it will be invoked in `20:45:28`

Dump ('adb shell dumpsys alarm' command on Android 8.1.0 device):

```
Batch{68ad18a num=1 start=1468562132 end=1468562132 flgs=0x3}:
    RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{faf73fb type 0 when 1652550328316 io.pelmenstar.testalarm}
      tag=*walarm*:io.pelmenstar.testalarm.START_ALARM
      type=0 whenElapsed=+11m58s237ms when=2022-05-14 20:45:28
      window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x3
      Alarm clock:
        triggerTime=2022-05-14 20:34:26
        showIntent=null
      operation=PendingIntent{71cf62a: PendingIntentRecord{8d1cc1b io.pelmenstar.testalarm.startService}}
```

I *partially* resolved the problem. If go to the App Power-saver manager (Settings -> Battery -> App power-saver manager -> *Some application*) and disable 'Scheduled background wake-up', the system really do not adjust alarms of this application.

The question is how to resolve the problem without disabling 'Scheduled background wake-up' option or how to disable this option in runtime or install time (without user interaction). I noticed that on some apps (like Facebook) this option is disabled, but I didn't do that myself.

Comment: How often are you scheduling an alarm for? You can only schedule one for each 15 minute period.

Comment: It's alarm application, so period might be less than 15 minute. System clock app can shedule alarm for any period.